# Using std::function as data member with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: c++, struct, c++17, std

I'm trying to create a class that has a `std::function` as a data member.

Something like this:

```
template<typename ... Args>
using Function = std::function<void(Args...)>;

struct UI_Element
{
      std::shared_ptr<UI_Element> parent;
      std::vector<std::shared_ptr<UI_Element>> children;

      Function<> callbackFunc;

      template<typename F>
      void registerCallbackFunc(const F& f)
      {
               callbackFunc = f;
      }

      template<typename ... Args>
      void doFunc(Args&& ... args)
      {
             callbackFunc(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }
};
```

The problem is that it obviously works for functions that accept no arguments (due to Function<>). For example,

```
void doStuff() 
{
      std::cout << "This function works\n";
}
```

Is there a way for me to register callback function containing an arbitrary number of arguments?

Or some other way, without using `std::function` to achieve what I want?

Comment: You will need to use templates in the signiture of callbackFunc.
That would make your class a template class.

Comment: Do you want to be able to do: `void f0(); void f1(int); UI_Element ui; ui.register(&f0); ui.doFunc(); ui.register(&f1); ui.doFunc(42);`? what would happen with mismatching call `ui.register(&f0); ui.doFunc(42);`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm want to be able to register different callbacks to different objects. `UI_Element ui_1; UI_Element ui_2; ui_1.register(f0); ui_2.register(f1)`. Having a templated structs accepting `Args...` solves this problem, but makes containers a problem.

Comment: So `ui_1` can only register function without argument, and `ui_2` only function with one given type?

Comment: @Jarod42 Basically. The idea is that different UI_Elements may have a different callback function based on what they do. It is possible for many to have the same function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `std::function` with different argument list is a separate class. Since a member can have exactly one type, the only way to achieve this is to hide that type.

So, this could technically be achieved by storing the function wrapper within a `std::any`. Maybe it would be possible to write a more specific "any-function" wrapper, but following "works":

```
std::any callbackFunc;

template<typename ... Args>
void registerCallbackFunc(std::function<void(Args...)> f)
{
    callbackFunc = std::function(f);
}

template<typename ... Args>
void doFunc(Args ... args)
{
    std::any_cast<std::function<void(Args...)>>(callbackFunc)(std::move(args)...);
}
```

This is not very nice to deal with. Reference arguments are disallowed (enforcement is not implemented) and you have to pass the arguments with exactly correct types, since implicit conversions don't work past this interface. So, if you register `void(int)`, you cannot call it with `void(long)`.

If you attempt to call with a wrong number of arguments, an exception will be thrown.

My conclusion: There is no simple solution to storing functions with unconstrained argument lists into a single type. This attempt certainly is not sufficient for general use.

Comment: `std::any` is too risky here with forward references, storing `std::function<void(int)>` and calling it with either `doFunc(42);` (`int&&`) or `doFunc(i);` (`/*const*/int&`) would throw...

Comment: @Jarod42 Hmm, maybe sprinkling a bit of `std::decay_t` might alleviate the problem. But I wouldn't spend the time to figure it out.

Comment: It seems OP wants templated `UI_Element`, but also be able to place them in same container.

Comment: `template<typename ... Args>
void doFunc(Args ... args)` or `const Args&`, but `registerCallbackFunc` should block "invalid" functions (accepts only pass by value/const reference).

Comment: @Jarod42 I changed to version that's less general, but at least less likely to throw at runtime.

Comment: You can still forward `args` so move-only type like `unique_ptr` would work too.

Comment: *"Reference arguments are disallowed"*. User can still be explicit... `doFunc<int&>(i)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 forwarding would be pointless without forwarding reference, but move is a good idea instead. The registering doesn't enforce the limitation at all :( I tried to register function with reference arg, and called with non-reference and got a deadlock...

Comment: We might be explicit with reference with `doFunc<int&>(i)`, so forwarding is useful. but indeed without explicit call, those forward will be a move.

Comment: @Jarod42 Frankly, I'm thinking that better approach would be to roll back the changes to registering so that any function can be registered, with deduction, and "force" the caller to explicitly specify template arguments. I wonder if there is a way to disable the deduction.

Comment: With [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity): `template<typename ... Args>
void doFunc(std::type_identity_t<Args> ... args)`.